# Nodejs ready file name from path

Tags: node.js, file, heroku, path, fs

I've used FS library to read the file inside a directory, if running in local, this Is ok. But if deploy my app on Cloud, as Heroku, how can I read the file in local machine from a path?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Directly read a file on your local machine *from Heroku*? You can't do that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I imagined 